# add Table only onto the last page of itext

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I have a code which has multiple PdfPTables in it.
The height of each of them is dynamic.
I need to add text like "signature" only to last page at bottom right corner.
I have created a signatureTable for that.
How can I get the last page if everything is dynamic and then add signatureTable to it ?
I have tried with two solutions - 
onEndPage() adds it to every page of pdf.
and footer gets on existing text.
Can anyone suggest something ?

Comment: How come you don't know when you've arrived at the last page? Once you've finished adding all the regular content, you know that you're on the last page, don't you? If not, please explain the problem in more detail. I don't understand why you'd need a page event (such as `onEndPage()`) to add something to the last page.

Comment: I want to add the signatureTable at bottom right corner of last page. After adding all stuff it will immediately add the signatureTable at the middle of page.. Its not the case that it will end up adding all the stuff till the end of page and then i can the signatureTable

Comment: In your attempt to use `onEndPage()` you used instructions to add content at given coordinates, didn't you? Simply use the code used there when you're finished.